# Salesforce API Connection to Sandbox

Tags: rest-api, community, api, soap-api

I have a contractor attempting to connect to my Sandbox.  He is asking for the following information to establish connection.  Can someone help me with the information below?

Thanks,

- Client Key - its a long code string

• Authorization URL - This normally looks similar to: https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
• DSR Endpoint(s) - This is where I will push the briefing data to. This normally looks similar to this, but please give me the full URL: /services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Conference__c/<>

Comment: IMHO, your contractor should have already known how to get the information they needed, or known where to look to know how to get the information they needed.

Answer (score 2):

> Client Key - its a long code string

This is what you do when you create a connected app. Go to Setup > Create > Apps, and create a new Connected App. Once configured, it will generate the Client Key that your contractor will need to connect their app to your org.

> Authorization URL - This normally looks similar to: https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

Unless you're using My Domain, that's *exactly* what it will look like. Even if you are using My Domain, using that should still allow connection to your sandbox, as it's a universal login endpoint.

> DSR Endpoint(s) - This is where I will push the briefing data to. This normally looks similar to this, but please give me the full URL: /services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Conference__c/<>

Nobody can give you the "full" URL, because we don't know where you're located (e.g. which pod, or if you're  using My Domain). The developer will need to use the `instance_url` parameter that they receive when using the token exchange.

For example, if you are on cs1, it would be: https://cs1.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Conference__c/ in order to access the Conference__c object's describe data in your sandbox.